# Где взять бэкап какой-нибудь большой базы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хотелось бы немного потренироваться на кошках в области составления sql запросов, индексов и всего такого. Для этого мне хотелось бы найти какую-нибудь большую базу данных с достаточно большим количеством записей в таблицах (более 100 миллионов). Может кто знает, есть ли где такие бэкапы в свободном доступе?

Comment: @ru_volt спасибо, попробую

Comment: Вынес свои комментарии в ответ. У so базы описана структура, да и она обновляется иногда, так что я бы попробовал ее

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stackexchange (частью которого является этот сайт) публикует [дамп собственной базы](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), правда я сам не пробовал с ним играть.
Структура базы в этом дампе в общих чертах [описана тут.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)
Если есть проблемы с импортом этого в sql, то по [метке data-dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump) есть несколько ответов по вопросам связанным с импортом.

Еще [список баз, которые можно использовать для тестирования](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/01/sample-datasets-for-benchmarking-and-testing/), может быть частью устаревшим, но большей частью полезен

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать взять дампы википедии: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html

Ссылка на инструкцию с описанием таблиц: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Википедия:Как_сделать_копию_Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 1):

Следюущий код достаточно быстро заполняет поля уникальными значениями.
Как раз подходит для анализа оптимизации, индексов и т.д..

```
While 1=1

INSERT INTO 'your table'
VALUES (NEW ID(), 
        NEW ID(), 
        NEW ID(), 
        DatePart(millisecond,GetDate())
```